# Stream a large Big-query SELECT with Node?

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I'm developing a Node.js program. We use Node to manipulate data every day that are store in Big Query.

Each day we have a high volume of new data (280 Go).

How to make a request on BigQuery on all the day and stream the result row after row ?

Now, we don't have stream. We just request all the data once.

I could use the sql LIMIT keyword. But the problem is that BigQuery ignore the LIMIT in cost calculation. If we LIMIT 0,10. It explores all the data of the day (280 Go). Idem for LIMIT 10,10 ...

This is my current code.

```
    const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

    // ... Some code ...

    this.bigQuery
        .query(Exporter.enrichQueryWithOptions(`SELECT e.name FROM  events))
        .then(results => {
            const rows = results[0];
            console.log(rows);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
```

Comment: I don't know Node but still BigQuery's backend responses allows results to be retrieved in a ["paginated"](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/src/job.js#L341) fashion so you could take advantage of that. If you are working with 280GBs of data though I'd recommend either working with [apache-beam](https://beam.apache.org/) or trying to make this operation within BigQuery itself instead as otherwise it might take you several hours just to run this job.

Comment: Thanks ! How can I run a job inside Big Query itself ? With Google Dataflow ? In my usage, I would like to format my data differently and push it in BigQuery again (in a lightweight format). And do it every day, or many times a day to process all data...

Comment: What I meant by running the job within BigQuery was to run a query against it already making the data transformations that you plan on making in Node (making BQ responsible for the job and not Node). If what you are doing in Node is something that can be already done through a query in BQ then this probably would be the best approach for your use case. Also I forgot to mention but currently Dataflow supports only SDKs for Java and Python so not sure if this is a good option for you.

Comment: As @WillianFuks has pointed out, you should bring your code to the data, not the other way around. Especially at this scale. You should either transform the data directly in BigQuery using SQL, or use Dataflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just used BigQuery Legacy SQL decorators to select only the time interval I need. So, I can't get a part of my large table and pay only for this part.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators

But note that you can use decorator only on the last 7 days of data !

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be what you need:

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#createQueryStream

That function allows you to build a query and consume it through a stream of data.

Answer (score 0):

As people pointed out, it is best if you can process everything in Bigquery SQL statement.

However, if you have to process the data in your application. Bigquery provides a tabledata.list API to read data from table directly.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list

Comment: Thanks. But I don't find how pricing is calculated on this API ? We only pay the readed rows ?

Comment: Tabledata.list API is free.

Comment: But table List return all the database partition in one time ? So 280 Go, no ? It's not really easy to handle and process on server side.